# Perl in terminal takes long time to load

Tags: perl

I am new to `perl` and wanted to run it from Ubuntu terminal, so I just typed `perl`. It is taking forever to load it. What do I need to do? To make sure perl is installed I typed:

```
 perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 41 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2013, Larry Wall
```

Comment: Perl does not have a REPL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) built in, and does not default to entering one. Unlike, say, Python and R, but like, say, Ruby. Perl startup time is quite ok: perl -E '' takes ~0.002s on my laptop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just type `perl` then it will expect to receive a script from STDIN.

It isn't taking forever to load. It is waiting for you to type a Perl program.

It generally isn't desirable to type directly into STDIN (since your code isn't saved and you have limited ability to correct mistakes).

Write your program in a text file and then specify that file as the argument.

```
perl myScript.pl
```

or, having made sure you start the script with an appropriate shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env perl`), and made it executable (`chmod +x myScript.pl`), execute it directly:

```
./myScript.pl
```

If you were looking for a Python-style REPL then you can [use CPAN](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/development/manage-cpan-modules-with-cpan-minus) to install [Devel::REPL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL) and start it with:

```
re.pl
```

[image: re.pl in action]